# wxPython SetStyle Not Working

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wx.textctrl

I'm using wx.TextCtrl.SetStyle() in my code, but it's changing the style of all the text!

Here's my code:

```
# Get all the words in my TextCtrl
words = self.GetValue().split(" ")
# Find out what the farthest uneditable word is.
farthest_uneditable = (len(words) // length_constants["words_per_block"]) * length_constants["words_per_block"]
# Use this word knowledge to calculate the actual farthest uneditable character is
farthest_position = 0
for word in range(farthest_uneditable):
    farthest_position += len(words[word]) + 1
# Make all the uneditable text (everything from the beginning to farthest_uneditable) have a grey background
self.SetStyle(0, farthest_position, wx.TextAttr(wx.NullColour, (84, 84, 84)))
```

I've tested this code and made sure my farthest_position isn't at the end of my TextCtrl (It's been in the expected position each time). For some reason though, all of the text in my TextCtrl box is getting a grey background.

Answer (score 0):

From the wxPython 2.8 documentation.  The last paragraph explains where your problem is:

"
**wxTextCtrl::GetRange

virtual wxString GetRange(long from, long to) const**

Returns the string containing the text starting in the positions from and up to to in the control. The positions must have been returned by another wxTextCtrl method.

Please note that the positions in a multiline wxTextCtrl do not correspond to the indices in the string returned by GetValue because of the different new line representations (CR or CR LF) and so this method should be used to obtain the correct results instead of extracting parts of the entire value. It may also be more efficient, especially if the control contains a lot of data."